# how to keep value of viewBag asp.net mvc in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

i have 7 viewBags   which holds data in view when the Page Reload (switch to another language ) the ViewBag value became empty

how to keep values of these viewBags after Page reload

i'm using asp.net mvc 5

Comment: you have to be more specific when you say `Page Reload (switch to another language ) `.. does this post back to server?  to a different action than the one that loads the page and sets the 7 ViewBags in the first place?

Comment: when i switch language  it post back to the same action

Comment: How about using TempData instead of ViewBag?

Comment: can i send them from action to view ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewBag is just for passing from controller to view. You would want to use Session state if you want to persist data on post backs.

Comment: but i will cost much to create 7 sessions for seven viewBag values